# isset($_GET[]) not echoing in php

Tags: php

I have a very basic question. I am trying to pass variable using url. So, I faced one issue as undefined index. To solve that i used isset() but value is coming as blank. can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Code:

Page 1:

```
<a href='print.php?id=$row[id]&rname=$row[rname]' class='btn c-theme-btn c-
 btn-uppercase btn-xs  c-btn-square c-font-sm'>Print</a>
```

Page 2:

```
     <td><?php 
     if(isset($_GET['rname'])){
     $name=$_GET['rname'];
     echo $name;
     ?></td>
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: There's no GET parameter `rname` in your url, it's `name`

Comment: Sidenote: You should encode the ampersand ( as &amp; ) if you are outputting that link in a web page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is your code

```
<a href='print.php?id=$row[id]&name=$row[rname]' ... >Print</a>
```

So you will only get value if you search `$_GET['id']` (equal to `$row[id]`) and `$_GET['name']` (equal to `$row[rname]`).

To get the value only if not empty, null or isset try to use `empty` maybe :

```
if(!empty($_GET['rname'])){
   $name=$_GET['rname'];
   echo $name;
}
```

And don't forget to change your code by

```
if(!empty($_GET['name'])){ // change rname by name
   $name=$_GET['name'];    // change rname by name
   echo $name;
}
```

OR

```
<a href='print.php?id=$row[id]&rname=$row[rname]' ...>Print</a>
```

As said in comment, I would use `<?= ...; =>` too to be sure to get the php value (it's an `<?php echo ... ?>` equivalent :

```
//change name by rname to use $_GET['rname'] :
<a href='print.php?id=<?= $row["id"]; ?>&rname=<?= $row["rname"]; ?>' ... >Print</a>
```

so you can use `$_GET['rname']`

Comment: Got my mistake. Thanks.

Comment: How anchor will get value of `$row[id]` ? without `<?php echo` ?

Comment: @skk : are you able to get value `$row[id]` ?

Comment: @C2486 I edited my anwser, I was ok with you since beginning but cannot be sure if the php var works like he did so I said nothing first...still good to mention it I think, ty for the comment

Answer (score 1):

You have written id and name in url of Page1, but in Page2, you have written rname, it should be **name**, that is from url of Page1. So, it should be

```
 if(isset($_GET['name'])){
 $name=$_GET['name'];
 echo $name;
 ?>
```

Comment: How anchor will get value of `$row[id]` ? without `<?php echo` ?

Comment: Author of Post may have already got values of $row['id'] through some php code and accordingly url in Page 1 will get filled with valid values for id and name in url

Answer (score 1):

In your first page modify the content `&name=$row[rname]` to `&rname=$row[rname]` and you will be able to `echo` the name in second page.

Comment: How anchor will get value of `$row[id]` ? without `<?php echo` ?

Comment: Sorry.. I didn't notice that there was no PHP tag in the question. Thank you for catching that.

Answer (score 0):

First print php value with `<?= ?>` and rename get param from `name` to `rname`

```
<a href="print.php?id=<?= $row['id']?>&rname=<?= $row['rname'] ?>" class='btn 
c-theme-btn c-btn-uppercase btn-xs  c-btn-square c-font-sm'>Print</a>
```

Then you can get it in php like below

```
<td><?php 
     if(isset($_GET['rname'])){
        $name=$_GET['rname'];
        echo $name;
      }
 ?></td>
```